# No support for Maxwell GPUs in Nouveau

Tags: nouveau

I finally got my Dream MAchine ready for primetime but it looks like Ubuntu does not, well not ubuntu may be but Nouveau.

I am trying to install fresh Ubuntu 14.04.02 ( Should I go for 15.04 ?) and I can't even get to GUI because I am getting Nouveau message saying chipset is unknown. I mean I guess I can try alternative setup via "dos" like UI and then hopping for proper GUI but what is going on here.

Can anyone tell me if it's possible to go via regular installation GUI or I need to wait until Nouveau guys start supporting Maxwell GPUs like 980, Titan X, 980ti etc.
[image: Screenshot or an error upon Trying or Install option]

Anything else I can do here ?

Thanks !

Comment: Just to clarify, are you are aware you can install without graphics?  Is this about wanting to use nouveau once you're up and running or just about getting it installed at which point you can switch to a different driver?

Comment: Alright I officially need help. First of all installing in command mode. What do I need to download. Will regular image will do ? And Second thing I need complete guide on how to install and if needed troubleshoot Nvidia installation. Because I am doing this on my gaming mnachine I need to be using "good" 3D Drivers and lately I had somewhat good expirience with edgers. I am sure installation is not that difficuylt to follow. But how about installing drivers.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem as a 980 Ti owner.

What you can do is:

1. When the GRUB menu shows up when you load the installer, select "Install Ubuntu" and press <kbd>E</kbd>.
2. On the next screen, replace the words "quiet splash" with "nomodeset", and then press F10 to continue. This will let you install Ubuntu normally with a GUI.
3. Once you finish and reboot, press <kbd>E</kbd> at GRUB again and do the "nomodeset" trick one more time, and it'll let you boot into Ubuntu and you'll have the chance to install the official drivers.